# Set Property Value Extension

Tags: .net, reflection, extension-methods

How would I code a "SetValue" extension that would allow me to set a property value like this.  I know how to set the value using reflection but I don't know how to create an extension so it can be done like this...

```
Public Class Obj
  Public Property myProp1 As String
  Public Property myProp2 As Integer
End Class

Dim myObj As New Obj

'Here is what I want to do...
myObj("myProp1").SetValue("ABC")
myObj("myProp2").SetValue(42)

'Instead of..
myObj.myProp1 = "ABC"
myObj.myProp2 = 42
```

Thanks,AD

Comment: You can't do it with that syntax. There is no method call there. You could do a `myObj.SetValue("myProp1", "ABC")`